# flutter StaggerGridView with child of ListView fully displayed

Tags: flutter

How to write a StaggerGridView with child of ListView in every single item in grid. I currently implmemented with this:

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4, vertical: 0),
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              itemCount: _data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                print(index);
                Project p = _data[index].keys.elementAt(0);
                List<Tasks> _ts = _data[index].values.expand((l) => l).toList();
                return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2, vertical: 6),
                    child: PhysicalModel(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                        // shape: ,
                        shadowColor: Colors.grey.withAlpha(10),
                        elevation: 6,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Ink(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 0, vertical: 6),
                            color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                            // color: Colors.white,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: _ts.length + 1,
                                // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int idx) {
                                  if (idx == 0) {
                                    return Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 12, bottom: 12, top: 8),
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              getProjectNameFirstName(p.name),
                                              style: NORMAL_BOLD_TXT_STYLE
                                                  .copyWith(
                                                      fontSize: 22,
                                                      color: COLOR_PRIMARY),
                                            ),
                                            // SizedBox(width: 8),
                                            Container(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                  horizontal: 4, vertical: 1),
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Color(p.colorValue)
                                                      .withAlpha(100),
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                                 ),
                                              child: Text(
                                                getProjectNameRealName(p.name),
                                                style: SMALL_TXT_STYLE
                                                    .copyWith(
                                                        color: Color(p.colorValue)),
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ));
                                  } else {
                                    // index = index - 1;
                                    print(idx);
                                    Tasks _t = _ts[idx - 1];
                                    return ListTile();)));
```

this is just my example code. Currently the issue is **since listview is dynamic, the height of gridview item can not shown all listview items**.

Is there a way to show all listview items and make it NeverScrollPhysics?

Comment: Can you format your code? The more succinct and better formatted it is, the more chance you have of actually getting help.

Comment: I am sorry stackoverflow doesn't support shift tab to back backspace. I have my purpose explained on first answer comment,

Comment: yeah the code editing isn't the greatest. I more meant to make sure you run dartfmt (or format doc in vscode/intellij) before pasting the code in. Also adding a few extra commas after your `ListTile();}\n},),),),)` would go a long way towards making it more readable as the formatting would shift everything left a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess at what you're trying to achieve here; it would be helpful if you could give a more detailed explanation of *what* you're trying to achieve rather than *why* your specific implementation isn't working, as that way someone might be able to suggest a solution to the overall problem.

The guess is as follows though:

1. you have a staggered grid view, each of which has a list of items
2. you want to display a full list in each element of the gridview
3. using listviews isn't working due to it not showing the entire list but rather scrolling (and/or having errors)

First off, is there any reason why you can't use a Column/Row/Flex instead of the ListView? Since a Column/Row/Flex newer scrolls, that should resolve that issue.

If that's not possible, you could theoretically set shrinkWrap to true on your ListView.

Comment: @rmimckenzie thank u! Seems your suggestion is right! Let me try using column instead. Since I don't need to scroll at all, and the whole size is not very big so there should not have efficiency problem.

Comment: @mtmckenzie Sorry sir, Column seems will caused overflow, it doesn show fully items either. Will overflow the grid height, why?